# GitHub pull request merge is disabled

Tags: github, merge, pull-request

I have a C#/WPF project hosted in GitHub as open source project. I also used `Crowdin` to help me to localize the application. I have configured Crowdin to integrate with my master repo in GitHub's. According to Crowdin's [document](https://support.crowdin.com/for-project-managers/integration/github-integration/) the translated texts will be pushed to a branch named `l10n_master` once the translation has been approved.

I tested it, and the translated files do appear in `l10n_master` branch of my repo. Meanwhile a pull request is also created. However the merge button of this pull request is disabled, see screenshot below:

[image]

Any idea why, and how can I merge it into my master again?

P.S
It looks like Crowdin used Travis.Ci for continuous integration (I don't quite understand why yet), but Travis.Ci has no way to build WPF code, and I have no idea how to disable Travis.Ci yet.

Comment: "*This branch has conflicts that must be resolved*"

Comment: It looks like you need to go through a Git tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't complete the merge until you resolve the conflicts. This should usually be done by doing the merge locally, resolving conflicts, then pushing the merged commit back up to the server.

See GitHub's tutorial on how to resolve conflicts if you aren't sure how to do that:
https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/